# Is there a better documentation for angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am integrating `Angular Material` in my Angular 5 app and sometimes I hit a dead end wondering what event is being fired after a certain action. The [Angular Material Website](https://material.angular.io) doesn't seem to provide much information about the properties and events of the components.

For example, I added the `autocomplete` component, but there is nothing mentioning an event firing on selection. So, I StackOverflow'ed it and found an answer that we could use the `onSelectionChange` event, but how are we supposed to know that?

```
<mat-form-field class="studentSelector">
        <input type="text" aria-label="Selected student" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent" matInput 
        [formControl]="studentControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selected($event, student)" *ngFor="let student of filteredStudents | async" [value]="student">
            {{ student.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Now I could use the `onSelectionChange` event, but I would like to be able to see it officially listed somewhere, otherwise it seems like there's a bigger risk that when updating the framework in future, this might not be 'supported' anymore.

The web site for [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) lists only the close and open panel methods. Am I misunderstanding something or is the problem in the docs?

Comment: the `autocomplete` mentions the `optionSelected` output. Which you should place on the `mat-autocomplete` element. And is probably the one you should use, instead of the `onSelectionChange` on `mat-option`. But no, there is no better documentation. You can browse around in the [source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/bf52a195f271d1efbc13599a45855f95589ff249/src/lib/core/option/option.ts#L111)

Comment: @PierreDuc You are probably right about the `optionSelected`, but again that must be a common use case, so an example would make so much sense. Seems like the docs have been rushed.

Comment: It's always helpful to check source code if you feel that the thing is poorly documented.

Comment: You can also see the [api](https://material.angular.io/autocomplete/api) to see all the methods, interfaces, etc.